# Selecting multiple tables from single table by distinct column value in stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a bit of a conundrum I need to deal with, and I'm trying to find a good solution to it.  I'm using MS SQL server 2005, and given a table where a uniqueidentifier column contains a data key to other information on the server.  What I need to do is select every row in this datatable (sproc from ASP.NET), but separated into tables based on this one column.  For example, from

```
------------------------------------
MyID    |  MyOtherData
------------------------------------
 4         asdf
 4         test
 3         qwerty
 2         morestuff
```

I'd want the following three tables returned:

```
------------------------------------
MyID    |  MyOtherData
------------------------------------
 4         asdf
 4         test

------------------------------------
MyID    |  MyOtherData
------------------------------------
 3         qwerty

------------------------------------
MyID    |  MyOtherData
------------------------------------
 2         morestuff
```

How would be the best way for me to go around this, if I don't know how many unique MyID values there will be ahead of time?

Comment: The real question I have here is why?  This could end up with multiple result sets....and could be very cumbersome.

Comment: I'm assuming he means result sets where he refers to "tables," but I am with Mitchel. What benefit does this offer over returning it all in one go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is not to do this in the Proc at all, but in the client code.

1. Write a query/proc that returns the
   distinct MyID values (SELECT
   Distinct MYID FROM MyTable)
2. In your app, loop through each
   value selected and call another proc
   that takes a MyID value and returns
   a recordset for that value. (SELECT MyOtherData from MyTable Where MyID=?)

Comment: Depends on how many of the result sets are being produced. Looping like that on the client side reminds me of performance problems I've seen where it took 200 - 800 round trips to render a single webpage.

Comment: That is true. There is a definite trade-off between a monolithic query that locks up resources for long stretches and a series of short queries that chew up time opening and closing connections (though the pooling should cover that). The ideal solution sounds like a redesign of the database or app logic to avoid the whole problem.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes to mind here, and it isn't a very good idea....but would be to create a Cursor, that works on a query that does

SELECT DISTINCT MyId
FROM MyTable

Then, each iteration of the cursor does the respective select...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try and rethink your approach as I don't think it'll be very scalable and I think trying to find a way to achieve this will not be worthwhile in the long run.

Instead, could you not return a single resultset, ordered by MyID and then handle that resultset differently in .NET?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a loop structure that iterates through a subset of the main table's IDs to spit out a separate result set for each set of tables.  This is ugly but hopefully this is just some ad-hoc thing that you're wanting to get out of the way and hope to never have to deal with again.

```
DECLARE @Entities TABLE
(
     ID int IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
     MyID int,
     MyOtherData varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @Entities (MyID, MyOtherData)
SELECT MyID, MyOtherData
FROM TheMainTable
ORDER BY MyID, MyOtherData

DECLARE @Count int
DECLARE @Max int

SET @Count = 1
SELECT @Max = COUNT(ID) FROM @Entities

DECLARE @MyID_Current int

WHILE (@Count <= @Max)
BEGIN

     SELECT @MyID_Current = MyID
     FROM @Entities
     WHERE ID = @Count

     -- Output each individual result set.
     SELECT MyID, MyOtherData
     FROM @Entities
     WHERE MyID = @MyID_Current

     SET @Count = @Count + 1

END
```

For something even uglier, you could instead of just churning out the separate result sets CREATE or SELECT INTO a new, uniquely-named table in your database at each iteration, and insert a particular MyID's records into that table.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Entities TABLE
(
 ID int IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 MyID int,
 MyOtherData varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @Entities (MyID, MyOtherData)
SELECT MyID, MyOtherData
FROM TheMainTable
ORDER BY MyID, MyOtherData

DECLARE @Count int
DECLARE @Max int

SET @Count = 1
SELECT @Max = COUNT(ID) FROM @Entities

DECLARE @MyID_Current int

WHILE (@Count <= @Max)
BEGIN

 SELECT @MyID_Current = MyID
 FROM @Entities
 WHERE ID = @Count

 -- Output each individual result set.
 SELECT MyID, MyOtherData
 FROM @Entities
 WHERE MyID = @MyID_Current

 SET @Count = @Count + 1

END
```